# Passing parameter to DbContext with DI

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I want to pass an additional parameter to the DBContext, like this

```
string myParam="xx";
string con="connenctionstring";
services.AddDbContext<IDbContext, DbContext>(
    options =>options.UseSqlServer(con, myParam)
            );
```

And in DBContext:

```
DbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options, string myParam)
            : base(options)
        {           
        
        }
```

Somehow possible?
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot pass dependency to `DbContext` in this way.

First, create a class:

```cs
class MyClass 
{
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Then pass `MyClass` as a dependency to `DbContext`:

```cs
MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options, MyClass myParam)
    : base(options)
{           
    //* Intentionally empty            
}
```

Then register `MyClass` as a singleton to `ServiceCollection`:

```cs
services.AddSingletone(new MyClass { MyProperty = "xx" });
services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options =>options.UseSqlServer(con));
```

Comment: This does not work for me. The parameterless constructor is called when I add my class as a dependency to the MyDbContext constructor.