# How to perform Dependency Injection in DbContextOptions

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am having issues performing dependency injection on dbcontextoptions.

I have a class that requires IMediator to be implemented via its constructor:

```
public interface IPermission
{
   void CheckValidation(int ID);
}

public class MyPermission : IPermission
{
  private IMediator _imediator;
  public MyPermission(IMediator imediator)
  {
      _imediator = imediator;
  }

   public void CheckValidation(int ID)
   {
      //codes for validation
   }
}
```

Note: This IPermission and MyPermission has already been added to startup for DI.

Now the big issue is I need IPermission to be implemented inside myContext class whose constructor does not accept any other injection.
This is my myContext:

```
public partial class myContext : DbContext
{
    public myContext(DbContextOptions<myContext> options) : base(options){}

    public override Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(Cancellation cancellation = default)
    {
        //this is the what i want to achieve
       _ipermisssion.CheckValidation(id);
       return base.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

}
```

Note: I used services.AddContextPool for DB connection.

i have tried the following solution:

```
public partial class myContext : DbContext
{
    private IOptionsSnapShot<IPermission> _ipermission;
    public myContext(DbContextOptions<myContext> options) : base(options)
    {
          _ipermission = this.GetService<IOptionsSnapShot<IPermission>>();
    }
}
```

But i am getting an error saying cannot resolve scope service 'Microsoft.Extensions.Options.IOptionsSnapShot' from root provider

Comment: Why not to add `IPermission` as a constructor parameter of db context?

Comment: It is not allowed when using dbcontextoptions. The constructor only allows one single parameter. @AndriyShevchenko

Comment: I'm pretty sure you inject db context via `.UseSqlServer` ?

Comment: Yes i did with services.addDbContextPool<myContex(options => )>

Comment: this thread seem to help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66383701/passing-parameter-to-dbcontext-with-di

Comment: I finally found solution to it.var myService = this.GetService<IMyservice>(); did it for me. Though i had to config my Program.cs I really appreciate your time and effort. Basically i learnt that DI is not only done via constructor alone.